# string unable to parse in URI in vscode API

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Console LOG shows : \Users\skhan\Library\Application Support\Code\User\summary.txt

as loop is using to replace the slashes

**its working fine in windows but doesnt work in ubuntu and mac, this is the example of OSX 10.11.6**

But when i try to parse URI using API i get the following error

> threadService.ts:217[Extension Host] cannot open untitled:%5CUsers%5Cjdoe%5CLibrary%5CApplication%20Support%5CCode%5CUser%5Csummary.txt. Detail: expected URI untitled:%5CUsers%5Cjdoet%5CLibrary%5CApplication%20Support%5CCode%5CUser%5Csummary.txt BUT GOT untitled:/Users/jdoe/Library/Application%20Support/Code/User/summary.txt(anonymous function) @ threadService.ts:217

Following is the code

```

```
while (tempURI.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            tempURI = tempURI.replace("/", "\\");
        }

        console.log("FILE URI For Summary Page : " + tempURI);

        var setting: vscode.Uri = vscode.Uri.parse("untitled:" + tempURI); //ERROR HERE

        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(setting).then((a: vscode.TextDocument) => { ...
```

```

Is there anythings more i have do to parse in correct URI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `uri.parse.file` to make it file and all things worked as expected